# How to convert millisecond to UTC dateTime C#

Tags: c#, xunit, datetimeoffset

I am trying to covert millisecond to UTC dateTime. I have managed to convert millisecond to local DateTime but not able to convert local dateTime to utc dateTime. When I use DateTimeOffset, I am getting one hour behind so I believe this is local DateTime?

I am unable to convert local time to UTC DateTime

[image]

Test Class

```
[Fact]
    public void DateTimeCalculation_MustTakeDateTimeParameter_InMilliSecond()
    {
        //Arrange
        long startDateTimeUtc = 1626987600000; //2021-07-22 22:00:00

        //Act
        DateTimeOffset calculatedTimeOffset = DateTimeCalculationHelper.DateTimeCalculation(startDateTimeUtc);
        var utcDateTime = calculatedTimeOffset.UtcDateTime.ToString(); //not working

        var t1 = calculatedTimeOffset.ToUniversalTime(); //not working

        //Assert
        string actual = calculatedTimeOffset.ToString();
        string expected = "22/07/2021 10:00:00 PM +00:00";
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
```

Static class to convert DateTime to millisecond

```
public static class DateTimeCalculationHelper
{
    public static DateTimeOffset DateTimeCalculation(long milSec)
    {
        DateTimeOffset epochTime = new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
        return epochTime.AddMilliseconds(milSec);
    }
}
```

Comment: The comments showing "not working" are much, much less useful than "I expected to see X, but I actually saw Y". But as milliseconds since the Unix epoch, 1626987600000 is 2021-07-22T21:00:00Z. It's 22:00 *local time in the UK*, but you're never using your local time zone. Your assertion should be 9PM, given that you're dealing with UTC.

Comment: You should also test for the _value_ not the string representation.

Comment: `calculatedTimeOffset.UtcDateTime` it's working. It may not be what you expected. A better question though would be *why* are you using a Unix timestamp instead of a proper DateTime or DateTimeOffset value? And even if there's an actual need, why not use [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: It's not clear from your question which version of .NET you're using, but since .NET 4.6 there has been a built-in method to do this, rather than you needing to write your own, if you're using a version where it's available: `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1626987600000)` returns `2021-07-22T21:00:00.0000000+00:00`

Comment: is .net 5.. i have uploaded image

Comment: Right - fundamentally, your expectation is incorrect, because your value represents 9pm UTC, not 10pm UTC. (But showing the expected and actual values as *text* in your question would be clearer than including an image.) (And as you're using .NET 5, yes, using `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` would be better.)

Comment: If you're using .NET 5 then your question is kind of moot, as you don't need to implement your own method as there's one built-in, at which point you don't need to unit test it because it's not your own code anymore.

Comment: @Toxic both the built-in method and your own method return `2021-07-22T21:00:00.0000000+00:00`. Images don't help. Post code that actually demonstrates the problem. In fact, I suspect the problem is the *localized string formatting*. Compare the date values, not the strings

Comment: @Toxic what does `calculatedTimeOffset.ToString()` return? Is it `07/22/2021 21:00:00 +00:00` perhaps? The invariant date format uses the US format, and yet you comparer with a European format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: While I completely agree that localized string formatting is bad, I think the *main* problem here is that they expect their original millisecond value to represent 10pm UTC, when it actually represents 9pm UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet sounds like incorrect interpretation of summer time rules. 9PM UTC right now should be 10PM in the UK. - I think. At least it was last year

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, I'm aware it would be 10pm in the UK. But *everything in the post, including the assertion* suggests the OP believes that 1626987600000 represents 10pm UTC. This is the main problem, I believe. (Note that summer time rules shouldn't be "interpreted" at all here, because there's no time zone involved. It's all UTC.) Unfortunately we don't know *why* the OP believes that the value represents 10pm UTC...

Comment: @JonSkeet oops, didn't notice. I was trying to make sense of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var longDate = new DateTime(132713856000000000);//{7/22/0421 12:00:00 AM}
            var dateNow = new DateTime(2021 , 07 ,22);//{7/22/2021 12:00:00 AM}
            var dateNowUTC = dateNow.ToFileTimeUtc();//132713856000000000
             var  utcDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateNow, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString("U");//"Thursday, July 22, 2021 12:00:00 AM"
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what this is attempting to demonstrate.  The first line is using .NET ticks (based on `0001-01-01`).  The third line is using a Windows FileTime (based on `1601-01-01`), and the OP was asking about Unix timestamps (based on `1970-01-01`).  None of those are the same thing.

Comment: in the initial post the question how do convert a long date that is in  seconds (value "2021/07/22")....The long value was wrong first of all and I then got the right value. Line 2 and 3 shows that its possible and its the same thing....you can go and look at the Microsoft documentation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind?view=net-5.0

Comment: The initial post is poorly asked, however the `DateTimeCalculationHelper` it shows clearly uses Unix time, based on 1970-01-01.  `ToFileTimeUtc` uses a different epoch - 1601-01-01.  Also if you look closely at your line 1, the year is not correct - so these are not the same values.